# PowerBI Dataset and Report replacement

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

So, I created dataset that can be used to generate multiple reports and dashboards.

I would like to publish to the web portal and allow report designers to create their own reports and dashboards. Which works great until I need to update the model. If I update the model and push the data set via Publish function it deletes the reports.

So is the only option for everyone to use PowerBI Desktop? What is the web-based report designer for? Is this only for datasets that will never change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Power BI file has reports in it, it will over write them. What I think is happening is that your users are updating the report in your dataset, for example adding a new tab, so when you load changes it overwrites them.

You need to decouple the Dataset from the reports. You can load your dataset with out any reports. You can then build reports using two methods.

1) Connect to the dataset using Power BI Desktop, using the connect to Power BI Dataset connection. That links to the dataset in a Live Connection, so you can build your reports from that. You can then publish your report. Any changes to the dataset will not overwrite it.

2) For the Web builder you can do the same, create a new report in the portal and select a dataset from that workspace to build your report. What the user needs to do then is 'Save as' and give that report as a new name.

Both methods just link to your dataset, not  build a report directly in the file

Comment: I figured it out - it's close to what you suggested to (2). The key was to NOT modify report that is Published with the dataset, but click on the dataset itself and create new report from there - name it ... the only issue is that the default dataset is there as well, and maybe confusing..

Comment: As you already figured it out, I would just want to add a point here, in case if one wants to retain the changes( made in Services) in the report  that was published with the dataset, one has to SAVE AS this report with different name. then publish the PBIX to the services, the impact analysis feature would show that this publish would impact 2 reports and 1 dataset, but essentially this would only replace the original dataset and associated report, the SAVED AS report will retain all its report pages only the underlying dataset will be updated. I'm posting this after testing this approach.